# APEX Triggers? Creating Reminders? Updating custom fields dynamically

Tags: apex, workflow, custom-field, picklist

When a custom field for my Lead changes (the user changes a value in a picklist) and saves the Lead, I want to:

1. update another field on the Lead object with a value (i.e., the user selects wait 2 weeks from picklist, i want to update a field called time_to_wait with TODAY() + 2 weeks (or whatever the selected value from the picklist is))
2. set a follow-up reminder for the Lead

Can someone lead me in the right direction?

What is my best option here?

Comment: did you look at time-based workflows?

Comment: Workflows should be good enough for this. No need for triggers.